# origami FISH thickness 8

Tags: mathematics, geometry, paper-folding

Fold the shape into a **rectangle** such that the rectangle is **8 layers thick everywhere**.

[image]

A puzzle for [this type of orgami puzzle game](https://omega-3301.itch.io/origami-puzzles) made by Ωmega_3301, similar to [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2042/folding-a-hexagon-to-a-rectangle-or-square-with-uniform-overlap).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Fold along the red lines like this: 
> [image]
> The blueness and numbers indicate the current layer count.