# ORTHOGONAL origami FISH t8

Tags: mathematics, geometry, paper-folding

Since [the last puzzle got cheesed](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/126131/origami-fish-thickness-8), we're adding a new restriction (in *italics*)

Fold the shape into a **rectangle** such that the rectangle is **8 layers thick everywhere**. ***All folds must be orthogonal respective to one another.***

[image]

Although solutions are **not** required to be applicable in real life, using an actual sheet of paper is a great visualization tool.

A puzzle for [this type of orgami puzzle game](https://omega-3301.itch.io/origami-puzzles) made by Ωmega_3301, similar to [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2042/folding-a-hexagon-to-a-rectangle-or-square-with-uniform-overlap).

Comment: Is there an app which you can suggest to help visualize?

Comment: Ωmega_3301 responded with: *"we did all of these without actual paper so maybe try harder"*.

Comment: "Is there an app which you can suggest to help visualize? – 
PDT"  --  A piece of paper might help to visualize this origami puzzle.

Comment: Although solutions are not required to be applicable in real life, using an actual sheet of paper is a great visualization tool.

Comment: When you say "all folds must be orthogonal", do you mean orthogonal to each other, or orthogonal to an edge of the paper?

Comment: I intended for the folds to be orthogonal to an edge of the paper, but I'm interested in solutions with folds orthogonal to each other as well so I'll stick with the more general one. Updated OP.

Comment: This is really tricky

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here it is.  Fold vertically then horizontally.

> [image]