# origami USHAPE t3

Tags: mathematics, geometry, paper-folding

Fold the shape into a **rectangle** such that the rectangle is **3 layers thick everywhere**.

[image]

Although solutions are **not** required to be applicable in real life, using an actual sheet of paper is a great visualization tool.

A puzzle for [this type of orgami puzzle game](https://omega-3301.itch.io/origami-puzzles) made by Ωmega_3301, similar to [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2042/folding-a-hexagon-to-a-rectangle-or-square-with-uniform-overlap).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Folding along the red lines:

> [image]
>  Numbers indicate the thicknesses of specific parts. The unlabelled parts are 1 layer thick.
>  Assuming the original shape is 2 units by 3 units, this rectangle is 5/3 units wide and 1 unit tall.

Comment: ///////intended