# origami WAVE t2

Tags: mathematics, geometry, paper-folding

Fold the shape **into a rectangle** such that the rectangle is **2 layers thick everywhere**. The grey part is not included in the puzzle; the purple part is the puzzle.

[image]

Although solutions are **not** required to be applicable in real life, using an actual sheet of paper is a great visualization tool.

A puzzle for [this type of orgami puzzle game](https://omega-3301.itch.io/origami-puzzles) made by Ωmega_3301, similar to [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2042/folding-a-hexagon-to-a-rectangle-or-square-with-uniform-overlap).

**This is intended to be a very hard and uncheeseable puzzle. I will bounty 100 for the quickest solve and an additional 100 for each essentially different cheese, stackable.** Bounties will expire at April 4th 2024 so I can have a life.

Comment: Am I missing something or is there an easy solution where you fold the purple semicircle down, then fold the left column over the center column, then fold the right column in half?

Comment: @xnor As bolded, the resulting shape must be a rectangle.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here we go...  Sorry, it is not the "orthogonal" type.

> [image]

Here is a cleaner image.  Fold on the red lines.  It might not be obvious at first, but everything falls in place.

> [image]

Comment: Correct and intended, will bounty when eligible.